# Export the Meshlab file to ABAQUS

Tags: meshlab

Can you please help me on how to export the meshlab file to ABAQUS software? Also when I import the file from Meshroom, I'm unable to read the textures/color in meshlab. Please give you advice on this.
Thank you very much,

Regards,
Prithvi S

Comment: Hi Prithvi, welcome to SO. It depends of what you want to do with abaqus. But probably, meshlab is not what you want as source because you want to create a mesh of tetrahedrons to do the simulation. Meshlab won't create tetrahedrons, try tetgen or coindesigner instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hi，first you should export pure tri-mesh stl file, then use abaqus-plugins- import stl, but it still is a hollow model; so if you want to make it solid, just go to mesh- edit mesh -convert tri to get, this will make the model solid if your model is closed and hollow.